# Truncate responsive image in Bootstrap media-body (Media object) in Firefox

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, responsive-design

in **Firefox** browser (ver. 37) responsive images (*class="img-responsive"*) in **media-body** element ([Bootstrap, Media object](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#media)) is truncate (cropped). For example in **Chrome** browser everything is good, and image is properly reduced.

Sample code:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
    <div class="media">
        <div class="media-left">
            media-left
        </div>
        <div class="media-body">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-g-1920-300-10.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
            media-body
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

preview from **Firefox** (problem!):

[image]

---

preview from **Chrome** (everything is good):

[image]

---

I know the bug with responsive image in tables on Firefox [https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=975632] but every solutions does not work in **media-body** because width of this element (Bootstrap styles) is set on 10000px!

Is there any trick which solves this issues?

Comment: code in action on **jsfiddle.net**: http://jsfiddle.net/cichy380/7dLv6qbw/2/